# Clear Color Swatches on Xcode Color Window?

Tags: xcode, storyboard

You know how under Storyboard / Interface Builder, you can assign a custom color and save it to the color palette below? How would you clear those and start over with all of them blank? I'm not sure how to delete them rather than overriding them with another color.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As of Xcode 9 / macOS High Sierra, the accepted answer doesn't work any more. The colors in the palette are now selectable/draggable - once a blue border appears around the selected color, press `delete` key to remove it.

[image: xcode color palette]

If you don't see a blue border, when clicking on a color, make sure that the "Colors" window is active.

Comment: I wasted so much time trying to highlight a color before I realized that the "hex color" field must be selected first :)

Answer (score 4):

Just **drag** the saved color to the **Trash** on the dock!!!

Answer (score 3):

I do not see any method of completely clearing your palette, but the single swatches get replaced with an empty one if you click and drag them over to another slot.

So for a simple solution to virtually start over (with the exception of 1 square) is by simply dragging all your colors over to the same square.

You can then just replace this single square with whatever color you want.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This worked just fine since I only wanted White, 50% Gray, and Black in there anyways. Thank you!